# Run multiple fargate task with step function

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate, aws-step-functions

I would like to run 5 instances of my fargate task with step function.

```
...
    "Fargate_task": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::ecs:runTask.sync",
      "Parameters": {
        "LaunchType": "FARGATE",
        "Count":5,
        "Cluster": "my_cluster",
        "TaskDefinition": "my_task_definition",
        "NetworkConfiguration": {
          "AwsvpcConfiguration": {
            "Subnets": [
              "subnet-1",
              "subnet-2"
            ],
            "AssignPublicIp": "ENABLED"
          }
        }
      },
      "Next": "Next_task"
    },
...
```

This is the Json I provided, but I can't save it because "The field 'Count' is not supported by Step Functions".

Do you have any idea of how to do ?

I followed the doc [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/APIReference/API_RunTask.html#API_RunTask_RequestSyntax) where the key 'count' is written ...

Thank you for helping

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, 'Count' is not a supported parameter: [1]

Supported parameters:

- Cluster
- Group
- LaunchType
- NetworkConfiguration
- Overrides
- PlacementConstraints
- PlacementStrategy
- PlatformVersion
- TaskDefinition

[1] Manage Amazon ECS or Fargate Tasks with Step Functions - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/connect-ecs.html

Comment: So it is not possible to run multiple tasks ?

Comment: You can run tasks in parallel with StepFunctions - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-parallel-state.html